# Mysql Import Finding File in Directory

Tags: mysql, rds

I'm trying to import a csv file from the command line after connecting to my RDS database. Unfortunately I'm fairly new to the mysql command and file navigation commands. I'm looking to navigate to my directory where the csv I'm importing is located. This is the directory path `~/Desktop/images.csv`. I know I use `mysqlimport`, but can't figure out the command to change directory

Comment: Managing external files can effortlessly be and probably should be done with a general-purpose language like Java, C#, Python, Perl, PHP, VB. Do note -SQL is a special-purpose language limited primarily for database needs (DDL, DML, retrieval). Save yourself headaches down the road!

Comment: what is the command you are running and what error do you get?